# Address book program in Java

Tags: java

I'm just doing a small program. It's an address book which has four options:

1. insert new contact
2. search contact by last name
3. delete contact by name
4. show all contacts
5. exit program

Just wondering how to get the insert contact part and how to store it. I've hardcoded one contact to test it.

Here is my code I have started

```
package addressbook;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class addressbooks
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //create a table to hold information

        String[][] addressbooks = new String[100][8];

        addressbooks[0][0]="Mobile Number";
        addressbooks[0][1]="First Name";
        addressbooks[0][2]="Last Name";
        addressbooks[0][3]="Address";
        addressbooks[0][4]="City";
        addressbooks[0][5]="County";
        addressbooks[0][7]="Telephone Number";

        //pre-populate address book for testing purposes and records

        addressbooks[1][0]="1";
        addressbooks[1][1]="David";
        addressbooks[1][2]="Needham";
        addressbooks[1][3]="Sraheens, Achill";
        addressbooks[1][4]="Galway";
        addressbooks[1][5]="Mayo";
        addressbooks[1][6]="086-1581077";
        addressbooks[1][7]="098-45368";

        addressbooks[2][0]="2";
        addressbooks[2][1]="Mc";
        addressbooks[2][2]="lovin";
        addressbooks[2][3]="Hawaii";
        addressbooks[2][4]="Hawaii";
        addressbooks[2][5]="Hawaii";
        addressbooks[2][6]="12345";
        addressbooks[2][7]="412-555-1234";

        //menu options
        System.out.print("Welcome to my Address book!");
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("\n1 - Insert a New Contact \n2 - Search Contact by Last Name \n3 - Delete Contact \n4 - Show All Contacts \n5 - Exit " );
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("\nChoose your option: ");

        int option = input.nextInt();

        if (option ==1)
        {
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter your First Name : ");
        }
        if (option ==2)
        {
        }

        if (option ==3)
        {
        }

        if (option ==4)
        {
        System.out.println(addressbooks[1][0]+
        "\t"+addressbooks[1][2]+ ", "+addressbooks[1][1]+
        "\n\t"+addressbooks[1][3]+
        "\n\t"+addressbooks[1][4]+ ", "+addressbooks[1][5]+ " "+addressbooks[1][6]+
        "\n\t"+addressbooks[1][7]);
        }

        if (option ==5)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not just using a class (instead of brittle arrays) and a collection?

Comment: Right.  Java's an object-oriented language.  There should be a Person, Address, and AddressBook class here.

Comment: Ok so all the name and numbers would go in seperate class, and all the addresses in the address class?

Comment: Rather than an address, person, etc class, I think an AddressBook and ABEntry class encompasses everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start like this:

```
package model;

public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // What else means something to your problem?  Birthday?
    // Constructors, getters (make them immutable), equals/hashCode
}

public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String county;
    private String postalCode;
    // Constructors, getters (make them immutable), equals/hashCode
}

public class AddressBook {
    private Map<Person, Address> contacts = new ConcurrentHashMap<Person, Address>();

    public void addContact(Person p, Address a) {
        this.contacts.put(p, a);
    }

    public void removeContact(Person p) {
        this.contacts.remove(p);
    }

    public Collection<Person> findAllContacts() {
        return new Collections.unmodifiableCollection(this.contacts.keySet());
    }

    public boolean hasContact(Person p) {
        return this.contacts.contains(p);
    }
    // etc.
}
```

I would recommend separating all that stuff about text-based IO out away from the fundamentals of your problem.  If you get it right, the next step is to write a web UI.  Most of the code will be reusable if you do it correctly.

Think about layering your app:

```
view->services->persistence
```

Model classes might be used in all three layers.

The answer recommending JDBC isn't wrong.  If you write your service and persistence classes as interfaces, you'll find it easy to swap out an in-memory Map of Contacts for a database version that uses JDBC:

```
package persistence;

public interface ContactDao {
    Collection<Contact> find();
    Contact find(Long id);
    Collection<Contact> find(String lastName);
    Collection<Contact> find(Address address);
    Long save(Contact c);
    void update(Contact c);
    void delete(Contact c);
}
```

There are lots of ways to do things.  I've already changed my mind: I've introduced a Contact class:

```
package model; 

public class Contact {
    private Person;
    private Address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of objects will greatly help you here:

```
class ADdressBook  
{  
   List<Contact> contacts;  

   function addContact(Contact contact)  
   {
         contacts.add(contact);  
   }    
}
```

You will want to use the methods that are exposed as part of the List/Collection API to make this easier on you.  Implementing the Contact class is an exercise for you.

Comment: there is no such keyword `function` in Java!

Comment: @GETah no kidding. There is no such thing as a professional programmer writing free code either.  If OP, a STUDENT, cannot figure out how to implement the above in Java than that is a problem the OP must address.

Comment: That is called volunteering and that is what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: @GETah: but there is such keyword in pseudocode :) Seriously, we are not supposed to give entire solution for homework question. Just a hint in the right direction.

Comment: I disagree about no professional programmer writing free code.  Lots of professionals work on open source.  What you're calling "free code" is posted all the time here.

Comment: @duffymo I should rephrase my statement: No professional developer should do someone's homework for free.  I would consider open source a different beast than providing homework solutions for a student.

Comment: You don't know that this is a student doing homework; I'll confess that I don't know it's not.  Do what you like, just don't make erroneous statements like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a similar program, I would recommend simply constructing a database, this also allows you to save data in between uses of the program. Using JBDC is quite simple, here is the site i used: http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

Comment: I disagree; an in-memory Map of values is even easier than a database to construct.  You can persist it by serializing it to the file system.  A database is handy if you already know SQL and JDBC and the number of contacts is large.

Comment: First thanks for fixing spelling, and second, I have found databases far easier to use instead of serializing. But for a small number of values perhaps there is little difference. I just found it easier when I received this problem myself.